# Why does this element think it is being hovered?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am making a web app, and I'm experimenting with using `PHP` and `JavaScript`. I have a page where the user can go and change their profile picture to whatever they want and can crop it and rotate it and stuff. Anyway, I have a label for the horribly ugly file upload input, and when the user hovers over it, a little camera appears. However, for some reason the element is triggering the `:hover` attribute before it is hovered.
Here is my code:

```css
.user-photo {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 35px 10px 25px 25px;
    background-size: 90px 90px;
    background-position: 5px 10px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat
}
.image-input-label {
    font-family: inherit;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

label.image-input-label:hover .photo-cover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.image-input-label:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.photo-cover {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 100px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    opacity: 0;
    top: -105%;
    filter: invert(100%);
    padding: 27.5px 20px;
}
img {
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="user-photo">
     <label class="image-input-label" title="Change Profile Photo" for="image-input">
          <img class="user-cover-photo" src="https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/49001978636_7a06d2db8b.jpg" width="100" height="100">
          <img src="https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/49002177512_edacf2cfd1.jpg" width="60" height="45" class="photo-cover">                
     </label>
</div>
```

Now, as you'll notice, when you hover on the photo, the camera appears. However, when you hover below it, it also appears. Why??
Here is an example:
[image: mouse not over element]

If you look closely, you'll see that the mouse is below the element. So why is the camera appearing??? The element does not go down there! Here is a screenshot from Chrome DevTools:
[![screenshot][2]][2]

Please help me out with this! It's so annoying and I cannot for the life of me figure out what I am doing wrong.
(I apologize for the horrendous pictures, I am doing this on a chromebook)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because you are using `position:relative` and `top:-100%` which will move the element to the top but will keep its original space thus the area of hover will also consider that space.

To illustrate your issue here is a simplified example:

```css
.box {
   width:100px;
   border:5px solid yellow;
   display:inline-block;
    height:100px;
}

.box:hover {
   border:5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<label class="box">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/100/100/100" >
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/20/100/100" >
</label>
<label class="box">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/100/100/100" >
  <img style="position:relative;top:-100px;" src="https://picsum.photos/id/20/100/100" >
</label>
```

Consider `position:absolute` instead

```css
.user-photo {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 35px 10px 25px 25px;
  background-size: 90px 90px;
  background-position: 5px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat
}

.image-input-label {
  font-family: inherit;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

label.image-input-label:hover .photo-cover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.image-input-label:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.photo-cover {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  filter: invert(100%);
  padding: 27.5px 20px;
}

img {
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="user-photo">
  <label class="image-input-label" title="Change Profile Photo" for="image-input">
          <img class="user-cover-photo" src="https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/49001978636_7a06d2db8b.jpg" width="100" height="100">
          <img src="https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/49002177512_edacf2cfd1.jpg" width="60" height="45" class="photo-cover">                
     </label>
</div>
```

Or make the image block level elements:

```css
.user-photo {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 35px 10px 25px 25px;
  background-size: 90px 90px;
  background-position: 5px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat
}

.image-input-label {
  font-family: inherit;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

label.image-input-label:hover .photo-cover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.image-input-label:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.photo-cover {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 100px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  opacity: 0;
  top: -100%;
  filter: invert(100%);
  padding: 27.5px 20px;
}

img {
  object-fit: cover;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="user-photo">
  <label class="image-input-label" title="Change Profile Photo" for="image-input">
          <img class="user-cover-photo" src="https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/49001978636_7a06d2db8b.jpg" width="100" height="100">
          <img src="https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/49002177512_edacf2cfd1.jpg" width="60" height="45" class="photo-cover">                
     </label>
</div>
```

Or hide the overflow:

```css
.user-photo {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 35px 10px 25px 25px;
  background-size: 90px 90px;
  background-position: 5px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat
}

.image-input-label {
  font-family: inherit;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}

label.image-input-label:hover .photo-cover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.image-input-label:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.photo-cover {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 100px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  opacity: 0;
  top: -105%;
  filter: invert(100%);
  padding: 27.5px 20px;
}

img {
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="user-photo">
  <label class="image-input-label" title="Change Profile Photo" for="image-input">
          <img class="user-cover-photo" src="https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/49001978636_7a06d2db8b.jpg" width="100" height="100">
          <img src="https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/49002177512_edacf2cfd1.jpg" width="60" height="45" class="photo-cover">                
     </label>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you! I totally forgot that elements with ```position: relative;``` still come into effect in terms of their original position. I will accept your answer as soon as it lets me.